# Fetching data from a ReST Micro service in angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch data from a ReST Micro service which gives me data ( username and password) in JSON format ( [{"username":"Mark","password":"mark123"}] ) through its endpoint 
"http://localhost:8080/checkUsers"

I created a simple application in angular 2 with userdetail.component.ts file and user.service.ts which fetches data from the userdata.json file placed in my apidata folder within assets folder in my application

Below shown is my code

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list.component';
import {  UserDetailComponent } from './user-detail.component';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    UserDetailComponent
  ],

  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],

  providers: [UserService],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

  providers: [UserService]


})
export class AppComponent {
  title = '';
}
```

### app.component.html

```
 <user-detail></user-detail>
```

### user-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-detail',
    template: `<h4>User Details</h4>'
                <ul *ngFor=" let user of users ">
                <li>username={{user.username}}-------password={{user.password}}</li>
                </ul>`
})

export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit{
users = [];

constructor(private _userService:UserService){}
ngOnInit(){
this._userService.getUsers()
.subscribe(resUserData => this.users = resUserData);
}
}
```

### user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
private _url: string = "http://localhost:4200/assets/apidata/userdata.json"
constructor(private _http: Http){}
    getUsers(){
    return this._http.get(this._url)
    .map((response:Response) => response.json() );
}}
```

can anybody please please guide through the process of fetching data from the ReST micro service in my angular 2 application.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: no error ,but i want to fetch data from ReST micro service .i need guidance so as how to fetch data from that ReST endpoint into my angular application.

Comment: I guess you tried to replace the `_url` value to `http://localhost:8080/checkUsers` right?

Comment: yes, i just replaced the url

Comment: i am getting this error in my console...    "Failed to load http://localhost:8080/checkUsers: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: can you clarify your question? are you facing the problem with url or you want to know where should you place the logic of fetching the data?

Comment: @mohit uprim  ..... yes i want to know the logic of fetching data

Comment: please guide me through this

Answer (score 0):

While working with the REST, we need to pre-fetch the essential data before loading (intializing) the component. To achieve this, implement the resolver and use the service as you implemented.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { UserService } from './user.service';


@Injectable()
export class UserDataResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private userService: UserService,
                private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return this.userService.getUsers()
            .map(response => {
                let users = response['users'];
                if (users) {
                    return users;
                }
                console.log(`NO users`);
                //navigate if you want to....
                this.router.navigate(['']);
                return null;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(`Retrieval error: ${error}`);
                this.router.navigate(['']);
                return Observable.of(null);
            });
    }
}
```

Now use this resolver with routes to load the data through REST

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
     path: '',
     component: AppComponent,
     children: [
      { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, resolve: { users: UserDataResolver } }
     ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

];
```

Access this data in the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-detail',
  templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-detail.component.css']
})
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  usersList:any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersList = this.route.snapshot.data['users'];
  }

}
```

If you want to fetch some other data while working with the component, get it through services directly injected in to the component.